# Movie where aliens/monsters electrocute people

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm looking for the name of a horror/sci-fi movie. This was a movie I watched a very long time ago, when I was still quite young (around 1995 - 2000). The movie could have been older as it was showing on TV. The feeling reminds me a lot about the series "Falling Skies". Here are some scenes and details I remember:

- The aliens/creatures were dark in color (perhaps dark red) and amorphous; there was one small one and another large one, could have been the same one which had grown
- Can't remember the creatures being intelligent and they didn't communicate, they were more predatory
- The one scene there are people playing baseball (I think) and the one guy runs to fetch the ball, he gets to the ball beneath a tree and the small creature falls onto his back from one of the branches, he becomes immobilized by pain
- The other scene the large creature enters someones bedroom and it has two jaws, like a bird's but turned sideways, and it bites the person's face in the bed and "electrocutes" the person (can vividly remember some electric bolts)
- The victims were burned into their skin with a certain pattern
- The final scene might have been in a power-station (the creatures had something to do with electricity, but this could just be my association), and there was also a scene in a forest

I hope these are enough clues. This might be a somewhat popular movie, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the movie you're looking for is called "Not Of This World" (1991)

You can view the full film online [here](https://youtube.com/watch?v=IYoaCEKkP6Y)

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you so much, will be watching this tonight :D